# Using Saxon-B or purchasing Saxon-PE/EE?

Tags: saxon

We have found the limitations of Saxon-HE (see  [table](http://www.saxonica.com/feature-matrix.html)) at the point of using **Extensibility using reflexion** and **EXSLT extension function**.

We are evaluating to purchase few licenses for the servers and development team members and we are short of time to evaluate every tool, considering that purchasing and distributing the license will also consume our time.

Apparently there is a previous version of Saxon called Saxon-B that saxonica is not longer maintaining but it claims to support **Extensibility using reflexion** and according to this  [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897664/how-do-i-get-exslt-support-in-saxon-he)  supports **EXSLT** too.

My question is, could we stick with Saxon-B (an open-source solution) for those features mentioned or should we purchase those licenses?

Comment: Saxon B is an XSLT 2.0 - only implementation. If someone wants the new features, available in XSLT 3.0/XPath 3.0, they definitely will need the newest Saxon (or other vendors') versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I am replying myself.

We have given a try to **Saxon-B** during last few days and it works perfectly for the needs we have (mentioned in the question). We have not found any minor/major bug so far.

Thanks Saxonica team for keeping available as open-source the Saxon-B version.

**Edit**: Saxon-B is no longer compatible with Java 8 and above.

Comment: You're welcome. We're well aware that there are different sections of the market with different needs. Fortunately at the moment Saxon-EE is generating enough revenue to fund the ongoing development of open source versions of the product for the benefit of those who feel unable to make a financial investment.